# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation on button that calls a function it resides inside

Tags: javascript, event-listener

So I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".
I have a function that populates a table with data, and in js creates the elements, buttons etc. and adds the eventlisteners.

My issue seems to be somewhere when I press a button which calls a function that reloads the tables data. The button is created inside the function as well.

The issue occurs when pressing the "resendBtn".
My JS:

```
const addTableDataForMailQueue = (applicationId, tableBody) => {
    // get emails

    getEmailsFromQueue(applicationId, function(data){
        if(data == "FALSE"){
            // console.log("Failure data", data);
        }else{
            toggleSpinner();
            // console.log("Success data", data);
            // loop over data and assign.
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                const idEle = document.createElement("td");
                idEle.innerText = data[i].id;
                idEle.setAttribute("data-id", data[i].id);
                const typeEle = document.createElement("td");
                typeEle.innerText = data[i].type;

                const emailEle = document.createElement("td");
                emailEle.innerText = data[i].recipients.split("::")[0];
                emailEle.setAttribute("id", "email"+data[i].id);

                const nameEle = document.createElement("td");
                nameEle.innerText = data[i].recipients.split("::")[1];
                nameEle.setAttribute("id", "name"+data[i].id);
                const subjectEle = document.createElement("td");
                subjectEle.innerText = data[i].subject;

                const bodyEle = document.createElement("td");
                const bodyButton = document.createElement("button");
                bodyButton.innerHTML = "<i class=\"far fa-eye\"></i>";
                bodyButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-icon");

                // On click show a popup with the full content of the body of the email.
                addToolTipToElement(bodyButton, "Se mail body");
                bodyButton.addEventListener("click", function(bodyEle){
                    toggleSpinner();

                    const mailId = bodyEle.target.closest("tr").querySelector("[data-id]").dataset.id;
                    const bodyPopup = showGenericPopup("bodypopup"+mailId);
                    bodyPopup.parentElement.classList.add("popup--md");

                    const bodyHeading = document.createElement("h2");
                    bodyHeading.innerText = "Mail indhold";
                    bodyHeading.style.textAlign = "center";

                    const bodyParagraph = document.createElement("p");
                    bodyParagraph.innerHTML = document.getElementById("body"+mailId).value;

                    bodyPopup.appendChild(bodyHeading);
                    bodyPopup.appendChild(bodyParagraph);
                    toggleSpinner();
                });
                bodyEle.appendChild(bodyButton);

                const bodyInput = document.createElement("input");
                bodyInput.setAttribute("value", data[i].body);
                bodyInput.setAttribute("id", "body"+data[i].id);
                bodyInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

                const lastAttemptEle = document.createElement("td");
                lastAttemptEle.innerText = data[i].lastAttempt;

                const actionsEle = document.createElement("td");
                const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
                editBtn.innerHTML = "<i class=\"far fa-edit\"></i>";
                editBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-icon");
                editBtn.setAttribute("data-mail-id", data[i].id);
                addToolTipToElement(editBtn, "Rediger modtager/e");
                editBtn.addEventListener("click", function(ele){
                    toggleSpinner();
                    const mailId = ele.target.closest("[data-mail-id]").dataset.mailId;

                    const editPopup = showGenericPopup("edit"+mailId);
                    editPopup.parentElement.classList.add("popup--md");

                    const heading = document.createElement("h2");
                    heading.innerText = "Rediger modtager";
                    heading.style.textAlign = "center";

                    const emailLabel = document.createElement("label");
                    emailLabel.setAttribute("for", "emailInput"+mailId);
                    emailLabel.innerText = "Email";

                    const emailInput = document.createElement("input");
                    emailInput.setAttribute("type", "email");
                    emailInput.setAttribute("id", "emailInput"+mailId);
                    emailInput.value = document.getElementById("email"+mailId).innerText;

                    // validate input
                    emailInput.addEventListener("change", function(e){
                        if(validateEmail(e.target.value)){
                            e.target.style.borderBottom = "2px solid green";
                        }else{
                            e.target.style.borderBottom = "2px solid red";
                        }
                    });
                    const nameLabel = document.createElement("label");
                    nameLabel.setAttribute("for", "nameInput"+mailId);
                    nameLabel.innerText = "Navn";

                    const nameInput = document.createElement("input");
                    nameInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
                    nameInput.setAttribute("id", "nameInput"+mailId);
                    nameInput.value = document.getElementById("name"+mailId).innerText;

                    // validate input
                    nameInput.addEventListener("change", function(e){
                        if(validateName(e.target.value)){
                            e.target.style.borderBottom = "2px solid green";
                        }else{
                            e.target.style.borderBottom = "2px solid red";
                        }
                    });

                    const hiddenMailIdInput = document.createElement("input");
                    hiddenMailIdInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    hiddenMailIdInput.setAttribute("id", "hiddenInput"+mailId);
                    hiddenMailIdInput.setAttribute("value", mailId);

                    const saveBtn = document.createElement("button");
                    saveBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success");
                    saveBtn.innerText = "Gem";

                    saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function(saveEle){
                        toggleSpinner();
                        const emailValue = document.getElementById("emailInput"+mailId);
                        const nameValue = document.getElementById("nameInput"+mailId);

                        // validate email and name before submitting.
                        if(validateEmail(emailValue.value) && validateName(nameValue.value)){
                            const formatted = emailValue.value + "::" + nameValue.value;
                            // update the name
                            updateMailQueueRecipient(mailId, formatted);
                            closeGenericPopup("edit"+mailId);

                            tableBody.textContent = '';
                            addTableDataForMailQueue(applicationId, tableBody);
                            toggleSpinner();
                        }else{
                            // help show which one is wrong.
                            if(validateEmail(emailValue.value) == false){
                                emailValue.style.borderBottom = "2px solid red";
                            }
                            if(validateName(nameValue.value) == false){
                                nameValue.style.borderBottom = "2px solid red";
                            }
                            showErrorAlert("Din email eller navn er ikke korrekt");
                        }
                    });
                    const cancelBtn = document.createElement("button");
                    cancelBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-cancel");
                    cancelBtn.innerText = "Annuller";
                    cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
                        closeGenericPopup("edit"+mailId);
                    });

                    // add "containers" to better display html elements.
                    const buttonContainer = document.createElement("div");
                    buttonContainer.setAttribute("class", "button-container");
                    const inputContainer = document.createElement("div");
                    inputContainer.setAttribute("class", "input-container");
                    const inputTwoContainer = document.createElement("div");
                    inputTwoContainer.setAttribute("class", "input-container");

                    inputContainer.appendChild(emailLabel);
                    inputContainer.appendChild(emailInput);
                    inputContainer.appendChild(hiddenMailIdInput);

                    inputTwoContainer.appendChild(nameLabel);
                    inputTwoContainer.appendChild(nameInput);

                    buttonContainer.appendChild(saveBtn);
                    buttonContainer.appendChild(cancelBtn);

                    editPopup.appendChild(heading);
                    editPopup.appendChild(inputContainer);
                    editPopup.appendChild(inputTwoContainer);
                    editPopup.appendChild(buttonContainer);
                    toggleSpinner();
                })
                actionsEle.appendChild(editBtn);

                // <-- Email is sending....
                if(data[i].success == 0 && data[i].errorCount >= 0 && data[i].errorCount < 3){

                    // is in progress of sending
                    const noActionBtn = document.createElement("button");
                    noActionBtn.innerHTML = "<i class=\"fas fa-sync-alt\"></i>";
                    noActionBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
                    noActionBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-icon btn-icon__warning");
                    addToolTipToElement(noActionBtn, "Forsendelse er i gang.");
                    actionsEle.appendChild(noActionBtn);
                }else if(data[i].errorCount == 3){
                    // error has occurred, contact support.
                    // unable to send
                    const errorActionBtn = document.createElement("button");
                    errorActionBtn.setAttribute("disabled", true);
                    errorActionBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-icon btn-icon__danger");
                    errorActionBtn.innerHTML = "<i class=\"fas fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>";
                    addToolTipToElement(errorActionBtn, "En fejl opstod, kontakt support med id");
                    actionsEle.appendChild(errorActionBtn);
                }else{
                    // no issues, ready to resend.
                    const resendBtn = document.createElement("button");
                    resendBtn.innerHTML = "<i class=\"far fa-paper-plane\"></i>";
                    resendBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-icon");
                    addToolTipToElement(resendBtn, "Gensend email");
                    actionsEle.appendChild(resendBtn);
                    resendBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                        confirmAction("Dette afsender emailen igen", function () {
                            // resend it
                            updateMailSentStatusForPenneo(e.target.closest('button').closest('tr').querySelector('td').dataset.id);
                            tableBody.textContent = '';
                            addTableDataForMailQueue(applicationId, tableBody);
                        })
                    })
                }

                const rowEle = document.createElement("tr");
                rowEle.appendChild(idEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(typeEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(emailEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(nameEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(subjectEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(bodyEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(bodyInput);
                rowEle.appendChild(lastAttemptEle);
                rowEle.appendChild(actionsEle);
                tableBody.appendChild(rowEle);
            }
            toggleSpinner();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why its happening, anybody have an idea?

Comment: `addTableDataForMailQueue(tableBody)` appears to be missing the first of the two parameters.

Comment: @Bergi ahh yep saw that, but in the actual code it is there. Just forgot to update the code here.

Comment: Then I can't tell what the problem is. Can you simplify the code to a [mcve] that we could run to reproduce the error? Or can you at least post the complete stack trace of the exception? Which method is throwing the "*illegal invocation*" error?